# Do we know what the degolim of the shivtey koh looked like

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes, dor-hamidbar, pictures, judaism

Is there any replica from the past of what they looked like?

Comment: We have the Medrash Rabbah that describes each flag in detail

Comment: Seems unlikely they stood in any particular formation. (Flags didn't really exist back then @sam. "Degel" is something like "battalion".)

Comment: I am going based of the Medrash Rabbah.

Comment: Rashi Bamidbar 2:2 באתת. כָּל דֶּגֶל יִהְיֶה לוֹ אוֹת מַפָּה צְבוּעָה תְלוּיָה בוֹ, צִבְעוֹ שֶׁל זֶה לֹא כְצִבְעוֹ שֶׁל זֶה, צֶבַע כָּל אֶחָד כְּגוֹן אַבְנוֹ הַקְּבוּעָה בַחֹשֶׁן, וּמִתּוֹךְ כָּךְ יַכִּיר כָּל אֶחָד אֶת דִּגְלוֹ;

Answer (score 3):

See Medrash Rabbah 2:7.

Basic description mentioned in the Medrash

1. Reuvein: Red flag and has dudayim(mandrakes) embroidered on it.
2. Shimon : Green flag with town of Shechem embroidered on it.
3. Levi : a third white ,a third black,and a third red flag with the Urim Vetumim embroidered on it.
4. Yehuda: flag the color of heavens with a lion embroidered on it.
5. Yissachar: black flag with a sun and moon embroidered on it.
6. Zevulun: White flag with a ship on it.
7. Dan: Sapphire flag with snake embroidered on it.
8. Gad: Blend of black and white flag with a picture of a machneh(camp) on it.
9. Naftali: color of flag was like a clear wine not deep red ,and had a hind(female deer) embroidered on it.
10. Asher: the color of flag was like a precious stone that women wore ,and had an olive tree embroidered on it.
11. Yosef: very deep black flag with Mitzrayim embroidered on it.
    A) Ephraim - a bull
    B) Menashe - a Re'em (Ox)
12. Binyamin: flag had all colors of all the Shevatim and had a wolf embroidered on it.

Hebrew text of the Medrash:

בְאֹתֹת" סימנין היו לכל נשיא ונשיא מפה וצבע על כל מפה ומפה כצבע של אבנים טובות שהיו על לבו של אהרן מהם למדה המלכות להיות עושין מפה וצבע לכל מפה ומפה כל שבט ושבט נשיא שלו צבע מפה שלו דומה לצבע של אבנו

ראובן - אבנו אודם ומפה שלו צבוע אדום ומצוייר עליו דודאים.
שמעון - פטדה ומפה שלו צבוע ירוק ומצוייר עליו שכם.
לוי - ברקת ומפה שלו צבוע שליש לבן ושליש שחור ושליש אדום ומצוייר עליו אורים ותומים.
יהודה - נפך וצבע מפה שלו דמותו כמין שמים ומצוייר עליו אריה.
יששכר - ספיר ומפה שלו צבוע שחור דומה לכחול ומצוייר עליו שמש וירח על שם (דה"א יב, לג): "ומבני יששכר יודעי בינה לעתים".
זבולן - יהלם וצבע מפה שלו לבנה ומצוייר עליו ספינה על שם (בראשית מט, יג): "זבולן לחוף ימים ישכון"
דן - לשם וצבע מפה שלו דומה לספיר ומצוייר עליו נחש על שם (שם, יז) "יהי דן נחש".
גד - שבו וצבע מפה שלו לא לבן ולא שחור אלא מעורב שחור ולבן ומצוייר עליו מחנה על שם (שם, יז) "גד גדוד יגודנו"
נפתלי - אחלמה וצבע מפה שלו דומה ליין צלול שאין אדמתו עזה ומצוייר עליו אילה על שם (שם, כא) "נפתלי אילה שלוחה".
אשר - תרשיש וצבע מפה שלו דומה לאבן יקרה שמתקשטות בו הנשים ומצוייר עליו אילן זית על שם (שם, כ) "מאשר שמנה לחמו"
יוסף - שוהם וצבע מפה שלו שחור עד מאד ומצוייר לשני נשיאים אפרים ומנשה מצרים על שם שהיו תולדותם במצרים ועל מפה של אפרים היה מצוייר שור על שם (דברים לג, יז): "בכור שורו" זה יהושע שהיה משבט אפרים ועל מפה שבט מנשה היה מצוייר ראם על שם "וקרני ראם קרניו" על שם גדעון בן יואש שהיה משבט מנשה.
בנימין - ישפה וצבע מפה שלו דומה לכל הצבעים לי"ב הצבעים ומצוייר עליו זאב על שם (בראשית מט, כז): "בנימין זאב יטרף" לכך נאמר באותות שסימנין היו להם לכל נשיא ונשיא:

Pictures of what it would look like based off the Medrash:

[image]

Comment: Picture found on reddit

Comment: Binyamin's wasn't any 12 colors, it was the colors of the other 12 flags.

Comment: The picture was not created by me and you are correct that Binyamin is not 100% accurate ,it is also missing Naftali